# Java Maven Spring Boot UnsatisfiedLinkError when spring-boot:run with own library copied at project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a default jersey project, downloaded from https://start.spring.io/ to which I added a lib folder and in it a library compiled in c ++ to be called via JNI. In Eclipse add the "lib" directory to the classpath and it runs perfectly through the "Java Application" option. When trying to run direct with the maven command `mvn spring-boot:run`, it gives me error when trying to load the library. my pom file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ec.com.extractdatacom</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestExtractDataDicom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RestExtractDataDicom</name>
    <description>Proyecto para procesar archivos dicom</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${project.basedir}/lib</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <propertyName>java.library.path</propertyName>
                        <buildDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</buildDirectory>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The error, only when `mvn spring-boot:run` is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ExtractDataDicom in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at ec.com.extractdatacom.jni.ExtractDataDicom.<clinit>(ExtractDataDicom.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I add the information.